# ajax error function always firing

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am running a validation to check if a name already exists in the db before submitting the form.  When debugging,  I click submit, the error function fires the alert, then the debug break point is hit in the ExistingName(string name) method.

ExistingName() is returning the correct value, but the ajax is ALWAYS firing the error function and the form is always being submit even though isValid should be set to false.

Can anyone spot what is going on?

JS:

```
$('form').submit(function () {

    var isValid = true;

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Event/ExistingName",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Name: Name
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.IsExisting);
                isValid = false;

            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('error');
                isValid = false;
            }
        });

    return isValid;
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExistingEventName(string name)
{
    bool exists = DoesNameExist(name);

    return Json(new
    {
        IsExisting = exists
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax` is being executed asynchronously, you'll need to take that into account and reformulate your approach. The `return isValid;` is not waiting for your ajax call to complete (whether success or failure).

Or, optionally, you can set `$.ajax` to be synchronous, but I don't recommend this.